# Approximating a definite integral to within a specific accuracy.

Tags: integration

I am asked to find

$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{6}}\:\sqrt{1+\sin^2\left(x\right)}dx$

to within an accuracy of at least $1/10$

My approach was to express $\sin x$ as a Taylor's series with one term and an error term. That is, $\sin x = x - ((\cos(t)(x^3))/6)$, where $t$ is between $0$ and $x$.

I analysed the error term and found that there does exist a $t$ between $0$ and $\frac{\pi }{6}$, such that $|\sin(\frac{\pi }{6}) - \frac{\pi }{6} + ((\cos(t)((\frac{\pi }{6})^3))/6| < 1/10$

I then calculated 
$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{6}}\:\sqrt{1+x^2}dx$

My answer was approxmately $0.55$

This makes me feel that my approach is wrong. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to perform the integration numerically?

Comment: I am trying to evaluate that integral within a given accuracy level. And I decided to find a polynomial approximation to the function I am integrating, then integrate that approximation. That's what I am doing.

Comment: I may be missing something, but it seems that you have only bounded the approximation at one point (${\pi \over 6}$)?

Comment: I used the point (π/6) to check if my approximation would give the required accuracy. The thing is, I know that for very small x, sinx ≈ x, and so I checked the accuracy of the approximation using the largest value of x in the interval [0,π/6], which is π/6, for it is for this value that I expect the approximation to be least accurate.

Comment: I don't mean the following to sound so critical, but presumably this is why you asked the question: I don't follow how you leaped to the $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ integral, or why you think that ${\pi \over 6}$ would be the worst approximation point or where the $\cos t$ thing comes from. I imagine the intent of the question was to find an estimate that is **guaranteed** to be within ${1 \over 10}$ of the exact answer. I have two approaches below, one non-standard, one fairly standard.

Comment: Thanks copper.hat for your solutions, but I do not get why you did not understand what I was doing, using a Taylor's series of a given function to estimate the integral of that function in a certain interval. But anyway, the accuracy we wanted to achieve in this problem could be, as I found out, achieved by even estimating the function we were integrating with g(x)=1. I found this through analysis of the remainder term in the expansion of f(x)=1+(sin(x))^2  So your solutions were "over-killing" this problem.

Comment: The point is to have a guaranteed estimate. When you use a Taylor series for this sort of estimation you cannot just pick the $t$ (for $\cos t$), you need to find an upper bound. However, you are right, $g=1$ would have sufficed as an estimate. In my second answer below, a better upper bound for $M$ would have given $n=1$ which gives the same answer as $g=1$ would have.

Answer (score 0):

PARI calculates these values :

? intnum(x=0,Pi/6,sqrt(1+x^2))

%6 = 0.5466247262542581602817603958

? intnum(x=0,Pi/6,sqrt(1+sin(x)^2))

%7 = 0.5454514560834487432208670304

So, your approximation is well within the given accuracy.

Comment: Ok thanks Peter, then I guess I can begin to trust my approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one slightly odd approach:

Let $g(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$. Then $|g''(x)| \le {1 \over 4}$. Using the
mean value theorem, we have, for $|x| \le L$,
$|1+{x \over 2} -g(x)| \le {1 \over 2} \sup_{|\xi| \le L} |g''(\xi)| L^2 = { L^2 \over 8}$.

In this case, we have $L={\pi \over 6}$  and the
range of integration is $[0,{\pi \over 6}]$, so we will get that
$|\int_0^{\pi\over 6} (1+{1 \over 2}\sin^2x ) dx - \int_0^{\pi\over 6} \sqrt{1+\sin^2x } dx|  \le {1 \over 8} ({ \pi \over 6})^3 \approx 0.018$.

We have $\int_0^{\pi\over 6} (1+{1 \over 2}\sin^2x ) dx = {5 \pi \over 24} -{\sqrt{3} \over 16 } \approx 0.55$.

**Aside**: We have the provable upper bound for $\pi < {22 \over 7}$, so the error integration
bound gives ${1 \over 8} ({ \pi \over 6})^3 < {1331 \over 74088}$.

Here is a more standard approach (simpler than a standard numerical
integration rule):

Suppose we want to calculate $\int_0^L f(x)dx$. Approximate $f$ by step functions as in
$\phi_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f({kL \over n}) 1_{[{kL \over n}, {(k+1)L \over n})} (x)$. Then, with $M = \sup_{x \in [0,L]} |f'(x)|$,  we have
\begin{eqnarray}
| \int_0^L \phi_n(x)dx - \int_0^L f(x)dx | &\le& \int_0^L |\phi_n(x) - f(x)| dx \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{{kL \over n}}^{{(k+1)L \over n}}|\phi_n(x) - f(x)| dx \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{{kL \over n}}^{{(k+1)L \over n}}|f({kL \over n}) - f(x)| dx \\
&\le& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{{kL \over n}}^{{(k+1)L \over n}}M(x-{kL \over n}) dx \\
&=& n M {1 \over 2} ({L \over n})^2 \\
&=& {1 \over 2} {M L^2 \over n}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $I_n=\int_0^L \phi_n(x)dx = {L \over n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f({kL \over n})$ estimates $\int_0^L f(x)dx$ with an error of at most ${1 \over 2} {M L^2 \over n}$.

With $f(x) = \sqrt{1+ \sin^2 x}$, a crude bound for $M$ is 1 and $L={\pi \over 6}$, so we want to find the smallest $n$ satisfying
$10 {1 \over 2} ({\pi \over 6})^2 < n$. Using $\pi < {22 \over 7}$ we see
that $n=2$ will work, and so we have
$I_2 = {1 \over 2} {\pi \over 6} ( f(0) + f({\pi \over 12})) = {1 \over 2} {\pi \over 6} (1 + \sqrt{1+ \sin^2 {\pi \over 12}}) \approx 0.53$.